# Polygonal shapefile: dissolving adjacent ones

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I would like to solve a issue related to a land use shapefile.

I would like to "merge/dissolve" just the adjacent polygons that have the same attribute. How can I do this using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Use native `Dissolve` algorithm, choose `Dissolve field` attribute. This make multipart geometries. Than you can use `Multipart to singleparts` to get single parts.

OR:

Use GDAL `Dissovle` algorithm, choose `Dissolve field` attribute and in Advanced parameters check `Produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry collection in the source file` which keeps the polygons as single parts.

[image]